# How to access the Popperjs object used in a Bootstrap 4 popover

Tags: bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am using Bootstrap 4 popovers (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) to display notifications but since the notification button is located at the edge of the screen, once the content is loaded the popover goes over the edge. I think it could be fixed by calling PopperJs functio scheduleUpdate (https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html#Popper.scheduleUpdate) after the content is loaded. However, I can't figure out how to get access to the popper data object.

How can I get access to the Popper data instance?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the update function, that's available in Bootstrap.

Check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#popoverupdate) for more info about it.

Comment: It's the good answer see : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-beta.2/js/src/tooltip.js#L405 Popover extends from our Tooltip plugin